# Пустая переменная $_SESSION

Tags: php, сессия

Есть страница с формой для логина, которая по AJAX отправляет данные из нее:

```
function call() {
    if($(".nick").val() == "" || $(".pass").val() == "" || $(".capcha").val() == "") return false;
  var msg   = $('#loginform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/templates/logincheck.php',
      data: msg,
      success: function(data) {
        if(data == 'ok') window.location.href = "/ucp.php";
        else alert(data);
      },
      error:  function(xhr, str){
    sweetAlert("Ой", 'Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode, "error");
      }
    });
}
```

Вот. Отправляет она их в `logincheck.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['password']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['capcha']) && $_POST['capcha'] == $_SESSION['captcha'])
        {
            require_once("connect.php");

            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `password` FROM `accounts` WHERE `player_name` = ?")) 
            { 
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $nickname); 
                $nickname = $_POST['login']; 

                $stmt->execute(); 

                $stmt->bind_result($password); 

                while ($stmt->fetch()) 
                {
                    $pswd = $password;
                }

                $stmt->close(); 
            }
            else echo 'err5';

            $mysqli->close();

            if($pswd == $_POST['password'])
            {
                $_SESSION['login'] = $nickname;
                echo 'ok';
            }
            else echo 'err4';
        }
        else echo 'err3';
    }
    else echo 'err2';
}
else echo 'err1';
```

Введены верные данные - идет редирект в `ucp.php`, однако переменная `$_SESSION['login']` пустая. В чем может быть дело?

ucp.php:

```
<?php

function createRedirect($where) {
$s='<html><head>';
$s.='<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url='.$where.'">';
$s.='</head><body>Ошибка. Вы будете перенаправлены <a href="'.$where.'">сюда</a>';
$s.= '</body></html>';
return $s;
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) die(createRedirect("login.php"));
```

Редиректит(

P.S. В logincheck'e сессия сохраняется, 100%. Дебаг ничего не показывает (error reporting'и)

Comment: Session_start(); забыли в начале файлика прописать то

Comment: @zhenyab понимаю, однако если в `ucp.php` прописываю, то Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Comment: @zhenyab однако, несмотря на варнинг вывод из переменной верный)

Comment: Всё. Поставил `output_buffering` в `php.ini` на `On`

Comment: Надо разобраться какие headers и когда посылаются

Answer (score 1):

У тебя браузер походу запрещает сохранение куков из твоего сайта. Зайди в настройки браузера и сделай так, как на скрине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]